# Show that $h(x) = pf(x) + (1 − p)g(x)$ is a PDF.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two pdf’s, let $p ∈ (0, 1)$ and let $h(x) = pf(x) + (1 − p)g(x), \ x ∈ R.$
>
> **(a)** Show that $h$ is a pdf.
>
> **(b)** If $X$ has pdf $f$ and $Y$ has pdf $g$, what does the pdf $h$ describe?

**(a):** I know that a function $c$ is a pdf iff $c(x)\ge 0, \ \forall x\in{R}$ and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(x) \ dx=1.$$

So since it's given that $f$ and $g$ are pdf's, the above must hold for both of them. Now I have that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x) \ dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}pf(x)+(1-p)g(x) \ dx=p\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \ dx+(1-p)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x) \ dx= \\ = p+(1-p)=1.$$

Also, clearly $h(x)\ge 0$, so we are done.

Is this all correct?

**b):** I'm extremely unsure of this one but I'll try.

If $f_X(x)$ happens with probability $p$ then it does not happen with prbability $1-p$, which is the same as $g_Y(x)$ happening. So I suppose that  $h$ describes the probability of $f_X(x)$ and $g_Y(x)$ happening?

Comment: a) is correct. For b), consider defining a Bernoulli$(p)$ random variable $W$ and set $Z$ = $X$ if $W=1$ and $Z=Y$ is $W=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job for part $(a)$.

For part $(b)$,

Let $$Z= \begin{cases} X, & \text{with probability } p\\ Y, & \text{with probability } 1-p\end{cases}$$

By total law of probability, 
then \begin{align}
P(Z \le z) &= pP(X \le z)+(1-p)P(Y \le z)
\end{align}

If you differentiate the equation above with respect to $z$, we obtain $h$.

Comment: @ Siong Thye Goh - Thanks. But the question was asking what $h$ describes. I'm not sure how to interpret your answer. Can you elaborate?

Comment: $h$ is the pdf of the random variable $Z$.

Comment: So, $P(X\leq z)=F_X(z)$ and differentiating this I get $f_X(z)$, not $f_X(x)$.

Comment: the little $x$ and $z$, they are just symbols.